# Como Criar quadro com texto em meio a pagina?

Tags: html, css, classes, div

[image: Criar estes quadros]

Como crio quadros iguais a estes , também com um pouco de transparência ?

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tava fazendo meio que esse trabalho básico.

Comment: Cara isso muito provavelmente usa algum Grid, ou do Bootstrap ou Foundation, ou qq outro grid... Vc quer fazer isso na mão? Existem mil formas de fazer, com float, com flex, com Grid, etc... Tem como vc explicar um pouco melhor o que precisa?